# Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player

I want to prepare my mediaplayer on this activity and when its prepared I want to jump to another activity and start the mediaplayer there. It doesn't jump to the other activity can you help me please?

```
        public void run() {

            try {
                mp.setDataSource(urls.getFirst());
                mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);       
                mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Start.this, RadyoBabylonActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
                mp.prepare();   

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
    });
    th.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue here is that you are trying to start an `Activity` directly from a background thread. I do not believe this is possible to do directly in Android - instead you must have the Activity start from the UI thread. Therefore, the way to do this in Android is to use a `Handler`. The `Handler` lives on the UI thread and receives messages from the background thread to do your UI actions such as starting another `Activity`.

Example:

```
//Inside your activity:
final Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        //Start Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(Start.this, RadyoBabylonActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

//Inside onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp):
messageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

See also: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html